# WinAPI перетаскивание формы, предупреждение CA1901, CA1060 NativeMethods

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

Реализовал перетаскивание формы за тело при помощи WinAPI:

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal extern static bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, uint WParam, uint LParam);

    [DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal extern static bool ReleaseCapture();

    const uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    const uint DOMOVE = 0xF012;
    const uint DOSIZE = 0xF008;

    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void FormMain_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ReleaseCapture();
        PostMessage(this.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, DOMOVE, 0);
    }
}
```

при анализе кода получил 2 предупреждения:

1. Предупреждение  CA1060  Так как метод является методом P/Invoke, 'FormMain.PostMessage(IntPtr, uint, uint, uint)' должен быть определен в классе с именем NativeMethods, SafeNativeMethods или UnsafeNativeMethods.

Как правильно реализовать класс NativeMethods ?

Решено, спасибо Uranus

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    public static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        internal extern static bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, uint WParam, uint LParam);

        [DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        internal extern static bool ReleaseCapture();
    }
    const uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    const uint DOMOVE = 0xF012;
    const uint DOSIZE = 0xF008;

    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void FormMain_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        NativeMethods.ReleaseCapture();
        NativeMethods.PostMessage(this.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, DOMOVE, DOSIZE);
    }
}
```

2. Предупреждение  CA1901  Как объявлено в вашем коде, параметр 'WParam' для P/Invoke 'FormMain.PostMessage(IntPtr, uint, uint, uint)' будет иметь размер 4 байт для 64-разрядных платформ. Это неправильно, поскольку текущее объявление в машинном коде для данного API указывает, что его размер должен быть 8 байт для 64-разрядных платформ. Обратитесь к документации MSDN Platform SDK и выясните, какой тип данных следует использовать вместо 'uint'.

Помогите с устранением CA1901 реализацией констант для UintPtr, спасибо.
Спустя несколько часов, начинаю думать, что ошибка в студии а не в моём коде.

> Предупреждение    CA1901  Как объявлено в вашем коде, параметр 'Msg' для P/Invoke 'FormMain.NativeMethods.PostMessage(IntPtr, UIntPtr, UIntPtr, UIntPtr)' будет иметь размер 8 байт для 64-разрядных платформ. Это неправильно, поскольку текущее объявление в машинном коде для данного API указывает, что его размер должен быть 4 байт для 64-разрядных платформ. Обратитесь к документации MSDN Platform SDK и выясните, какой тип данных следует использовать вместо 'UIntPtr'.

Это замкнутый круг ? или всё-же есть панацея, по прежнему прошу помочь.

Comment: лучше не редактировать свой вопрос, а задавать новый, со ссылкой на старый, если это необходимо. Но еще лучше - сформулировать новый вопрос так, чтобы избавиться от ссылки. Дело в том, что сейчас получился большой сложный вопрос, решение которого размазано на два ответа. Такой ответ как правило не несет пользы никому, кроме одного человека. Маловероятно, что у других будет именно такая проблема. Чаще наоборот, проблемы у разных людей пересекаются частично. Вот почему точные вопросы и ответы гораздо ценнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно было сделать приведение типов **uint** к **IntPtr**.

```
public static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal extern static bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr WParam, IntPtr LParam);

    [DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal extern static bool ReleaseCapture();
}

const uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
const uint DOMOVE = 0xF012;
const uint DOSIZE = 0xF008;

private void FormMain_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    NativeMethods.ReleaseCapture();
    NativeMethods.PostMessage(this.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, (IntPtr)DOMOVE, (IntPtr)0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Просто объявите статический класс с именем NativeMethods и перенесите туда PostMessage и ReleaseCapture заменив internal на public.
2. Согласно [описанию в документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182284.aspx), рекомендуется заменить фиксированный тип uint на платформо-зависимый UIntPtr.

Comment: Для сборок x86 и AnyCpu  `ulong` будет ошибкой.

Comment: @Vitalino Grom, обратите внимание что я добавил правку во второй пункт, по совету в комментариях.

Comment: @DigitalCore, большое спасибо

Comment: @Uranus спасибо, с  NativeMethods всё получилось, а вот с UIntPtr проблема, не могу правильно задать константы,  помогите.